# HTML5 audio & Piracy

Tags: html5-audio, piracy

I've implemented a HTML5 audio player as follows:

```
<audio controls class="audioPlayer">
    <source src="/pathtofiles/fileName.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="/pathtofiles/fileName.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

The 'pathtofiles' directory is non-browsable.

Obviously a user can inspect the code and 'open in new tab' and the audio file plays independantly.

The question is, how safe is HTML5 audio ?

Can a user download the file ?

Does the file appear somewhere (downloaded) into the browser cache ?

(If yes, is there anyway around this ?)

**Note - I know that 'experts' can get anything displayed/played in a browser as Scott says. The question is really more aimed at non-experts/casual users...

Comment: One way or another... I can grab *anything* my browser displays/plays. No exceptions.

Comment: @scott - I understand that 'experts' can do anything, but the question is really aimed at 'normal/casual' users . . .

Comment: It doesn't take an "expert" -- if someone wants something.. they can get it. I can launch a screen recorder and grab whatever it is that way... no expertise needed. If you don't want something stolen.. don't put it on the internet.